# Check if at least one key of dict is contained in another dict

Tags: python, validation, dictionary

I want to check if at least one key from a given dict is available in another dict.
I already know how to check for "must"-keys like this:

```
valid_data = []
needed_keys = (key1, key2)

for d in data:
    if not all(key in d for key in needed_keys):
        continue  # ignore invalid object

    valid_data.append(d)
```

data is here a list of dicts. With this code only items which contain both, key1 and key2 are appended to valid_data.

Is there something like:

```
if not any(key in d for key in needed_keys)
```

which also succeeds if any key from the needed keys is available?

Comment: have you actually tried your code - the function `any` exists and does what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [set intersections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
needed_keys = {key1, key2}

for d in data:
    if needed_keys.intersection(d):
        valid_data.append(d)
```

The intersection is only empty if no keys are shared between the `needed_keys` set and the dictionary.

Note that your `any(...)` function would work too, just not as efficiently as the set intersection option; perhaps you didn't realise that the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) actually exists?

Comment: Agree with intersections. nice and easy

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your data is like this

```
>>> d1, d2 = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3}, {"b" : 1, "c" : 2, "d" : 3}
```

First, define the needed keys as a set. Lets say,

```
>>> needed_keys = {"a", "b", "d"}
```

Now, you can simply check if both the dictionary keys and the `needed_keys` have atleast one item in common, with [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) set operation, like this

```
>>> [item for item in (d1, d2) if not needed_keys.isdisjoint(item)]
```

This will be very efficient, since it will return immediately if it finds a single common element.